# Which process sends SIGKILL and terminates all SSH connections on/to my Namecheap Server?

Tags: linux, namecheap, sigkill

I've been trying to troubleshoot this problem for some days now.
A couple of minutes after starting an SSH connection to my Namecheap server (on Mac/windows/cPanel's "Terminal"), it crashes and give the following error message :

> Error: The connection to the server ended in failure at {TIME} PM. (SIGKILL)

and :

> Exit Code: 137

I've tried to create some kind of log file for any SIGKILL signal, but, it seems like none can be made on a Namecheap server :

- `auditctl` doesn't exist,
- We can't get `systemtap` because no package managers are available.

Precision :

- `uname -a` : Linux [-n] 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.78.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 26 08:20:27 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- I calculated the time between each crash : around 6min.

I don't have a very good knowledge of Linux servers, and maybe didn't include needed information. So please ask for any specificities!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Linux server administration questions should be posted to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: The most common reason for SIGKILL is not another process, but the kernel itself, which will SIGKILL various processes when the system runs out of memory.  Check your syslog files for references to "oom", and think about whether the system may be low on memory.